# JPA constraint validation not visible in p:message

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, primefaces

Java 1.7, spring-core-4.3.10, spring-data-jpa-1.11.3, spring-security-web-4.0.1, hibernet-validator-5.4.1, hibernate-core-5.0.12, primefaces-6.0

I have an entity/database table with constraint

```
@Column(name = "E_POSTA_KO", length = 100)
@Size(min=15, message = "Ni dovolj dolg e-mail naslov")
private String ePostaKo;
```

When this constraint is violated, the message should propagate to Primefaces `p:message` element. I know this works, because I performed this on one other simple test application, when following tutorial "JSF & PrimeFaces & Spring tutorial" by Jiri Pinkas. But in the case of my real application, the message is not propagated from JPA to Primefaces. I can see in log that validation is performed and violation is detected, but I can't get this in other level. Maybe somebody can see from the log, what is the reason. Any hint appreciated very much.

```
22:40:08.726 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [si.scit.odpadkiporocanja.service.OdpcPrijaveRegistracijeService.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
22:40:08.727 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@41e6dbec] for JPA transaction
22:40:08.727 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@547d8d35]
22:40:08.727 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@41e6dbec] for JPA transaction
22:40:08.728 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
Hibernate: select REGI_SEQ.nextval from dual
22:40:08.730 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
22:40:08.730 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@41e6dbec]
22:40:08.731 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@41e6dbec] after transaction
22:40:08.731 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
nov. 06, 2017 10:40:08 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{odpcPrijaveRegistracijeController.confirmPrijava()}: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
javax.faces.FacesException: #{odpcPrijaveRegistracijeController.confirmPrijava()}: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at si.scit.odpadkiporocanja.service.OdpcPrijaveRegistracijeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4ace2879.save(<generated>)
    at si.scit.odpadkiporocanja.controller.OdpcPrijaveRegistracijeController.confirmPrijava(OdpcPrijaveRegistracijeController.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [si.scit.odpadkiporocanja.entity.OdpcPrijaveRegistracije] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Ni dovlj dolg e-mail naslov', propertyPath=ePostaKo, rootBeanClass=class si.scit.odpadkiporocanja.entity.OdpcPrijaveRegistracije, messageTemplate='Ni dovlj dolg e-mail naslov'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 48 more

nov. 06, 2017 10:40:08 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at si.scit.odpadkiporocanja.service.OdpcPrijaveRegistracijeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4ace2879.save(<generated>)
    at si.scit.odpadkiporocanja.controller.OdpcPrijaveRegistracijeController.confirmPrijava(OdpcPrijaveRegistracijeController.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [si.scit.odpadkiporocanja.entity.OdpcPrijaveRegistracije] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Ni dovolj dolg e-mail naslov', propertyPath=ePostaKo, rootBeanClass=class si.scit.odpadkiporocanja.entity.OdpcPrijaveRegistracije, messageTemplate='Ni dovlj dolg e-mail naslov'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Tried PF 6.1? Tried PF 6.2-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Didn't tried yet PF 6.1. But I think there is some general problem in my application configuration, because no exception is propagated from model layer (which is Spring Data JPA+Hibernate) to view/controller layer (which is JSF+Primefaces).
What are typical thing to check in such configuration?
If nothing will help, I'll build a small example from the ground again, to see where/when it starts to fail ...

Comment: No idea, I don't use Spring-data